# Dual Booting with Windows Problem

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, 18.04, dell

I have a Dell XPS 15 (9560) that came preloaded with Windows 10 Pro. I used a bootable Ubuntu 18.04 USB to run Ubuntu through the USB, then I used Gparted and wiped the hard drive clean (SSD 1TB), after which I installed Ubuntu 18.04 as the only operating system on the machine. I have been using Windows 10 in Virtualbox within Ubuntu for some time, but I now need to use some labor intensive programs that I believe require installing Windows 10 on the hard drive in another partition to work better.

I created a Windows 10 USB using rufus 3.0 which formatted the USB as a FAT32 (Large). When I entered the boot options upon startup, the computer failed to see the see the USB drive (UEFI boot options). I am assuming that I am missing a Windows Booting tool of some sort that would allow me to see this usb drive and boot to it.

Long story short, I have loaded an Ubuntu bootable USB now, and have completely wiped the hard drive and created one large partition formatted as NTFS in order to do a clean install of Windows and then install Ubuntu as a dual boot rather than trying to install Windows after Ubuntu. I am now left with a completely empty hard drive with one primary partition formatted as NTFS. I am still unable to see the Windows 10 bootable USB in my boot options.

In my bios settings, the boot sequence is set to UEFI and the only boot option that appears is "ubuntu".

Under "Advanced Boot Options", neither of the "Enable Legacy Option ROMs" or "Enable UEFI Network Stack" boxes are checked.

"UEFI Boot Path Security" is set to "Always, Except Internal HDD".

Under "System Configuration" I have the SATA Operation set to AHCI.

Secure Boot is disabled.

When I plug in my Windows 10 bootable USB and start the computer and enter the boot option menu, I still fail to see the bootable USB in my UEFI options. However, I am able to see the Ubuntu bootable USB just fine and even load to it.

The bottom line is, I know that this isn't strictly an Ubuntu question, however, I figure that someone on here has run into this problem before and knows a solution. I intend on installing Windows, then installing Ubuntu on a separate partition like I probably should have done in the first place. Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: What installation source  are you using for Win10?

Comment: I downloaded the iso on an up-to-date Windows 10 machine at this website: https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10

Comment: I had a recent issue when I made a UFD which was a Windows Repair Disk, but would not show up on my UEFI boot options, but did show in the MBR legacy options. As my BIOS was running in UEFI, the legacy options were useless as none of them would boot a device. I found the only way round this was to clean the UFD, then convert it to GPT, make a primary partition, format to FAT32, then extract the ISO files to it. After that, the UFD appeared in the UEFI boot selection and I could boot from it without further issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry it took me a while to get back to this. I found the answer to my problem, and hopefully this will help others in the future.

When I installed Ubuntu 18.04 onto the hard drive, it used GRUB as the bootloader and wrote over the windows boot loader. Since I installed Ubuntu in UEFI, this became the new default method of loading the operating system. Here's how I fixed things:

1. From a windows machine, go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 and download the media creator tool. (This is important, because installing the windows 10 iso with rufus didn't work. I imagine the windows media creator added something to help start the install).
2. Start Dell Laptop and enter bios settings menu (F2) at splash screen.
3. Select "Restore Settings" and choose "BIOS Defaults". This will eliminate whatever part of the GRUB that was left causing the windows install to fail.
4. Shut down computer, plug in Windows 10 USB created with the Windows Media Creation Tool, start up computer and boot from USB by pressing F12 at the splash screen. Choose the USB under UEFI Options.
5. The windows install should start, and you should be able to install a fully functioning Windows 10. Then you are good to install the Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 as you would with any other dual boot situation.

Needless to say, I learned my dual boot lesson, windows first, THEN Linux.